# Nested Fieldset with dependency injection in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, fieldset

I followed zend [Advanced use of forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html) to solve my problem.

Scenario:
I have two fieldset. JudgesFieldset and JudgesCareerFieldset (one judge has multiple career so i need to use collection in judge fieldset). JudgesCareerFieldset has doctrine 2 object manager dependency for creating select element and create service of JudgesCareerFieldset in module.php as described in the [Advanced use of forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html). Everything is fine and working and create form successfully. The code and example shown below.

```
class JudgesCareerFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {
private $entityManager;
public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager) {
    parent::__construct('judges-career');

    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager))
            ->setObject(new Judges());

        //fields of the entity
}
```

and

```
class JudgesFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface {
private $entityManager;
public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager) {
    parent::__construct('judges');

    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager))
            ->setObject(new Judges());

    //Remaining Fields of the Judge entities
}

public function init() {
    $this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
         'name' => 'judgeCareer',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Please Judge Career',
             'count' => 2,
             'should_create_template' => true,
             'allow_add' => true,
             'target_element' => array(
                 'type' => 'CaseLaw\Judges\Form\JudgesCareerFieldset'
             ),
         ),
     ));
}}
```

and form code

```
class JudgesFieldsetForm extends Form {

public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager) {
    parent::__construct('Judges');


    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
         ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager));

    $judgesFieldset = new \Caselaw\Judges\Form\JudgesFieldset($entityManager);
    $judgesFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
    $this->add($judgesFieldset);


    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Add Judge',
            'id'    => 'submit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
        ),
    ));
}}
```

**Problem:
In the view script when I tried to display collection it will display this error "No element by the name of [judgeCareer] found in form". How can i get judgeCareer collection ?**

**Error:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing in collection code in JudgesFieldset class.

```
$this->add(array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
     'name' => 'judgeCareer',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Please Judge Career',
         'count' => 2,
         'should_create_template' => true,
         'allow_add' => true,
         'target_element' => array(
             'type' => 'CaseLaw\Judges\Form\JudgesCareerFieldset'
         ),
     ),
 ));
```

Change to

```
$this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
         'name' => 'judgeCareer',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Please choose categories for this product',
             'count' => 2,
             'should_create_template' => true,
             'allow_add' => true,
             'target_element' => new \Caselaw\Judges\Form\JudgesCareerFieldset($this->entityManager)
         ),
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a collection named `judgeCareer`, but your `JudgesCareerFieldset` object has the name `judges-career`. Change the name and the `Zend\Form\Fieldset` should find your fieldset.

Comment: Thanks for the time. But this is not a problem as you mentioned above. after spent some time on my problem i found that, If i add Zend form collection in constructor of the fieldset instead of init() it displays this error (Argument 1 passed to Caselaw\Judges\Form\JudgesCareerFieldset::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given,). To solve this i add a factroy in module.php getFormElementConfig() to handle dependency of "JudgesCareerFieldset". but this factory doesn't inject object manager.

Comment: This is my factory for "JudgesCareerFieldset" in module.php used in collection 


public function getFormElementConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'JudgesCareerFieldset' => function($sm) {
                    $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                    return new \Caselaw\Tags\Form\TagsFieldsetForm($entityManager);
                },
            )
        );
    }